# visualize lagged independent variable models

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am looking for a way to visualize lagged independent variable regression models, preferably using ggplot. I am particularly interested in visualizing how the impact of the independent variable changes over time, meaning at  `lag = 0` , `lag = 1` , `lag= 2`. Below you can access an exemplary regression model and data:

```
model_test = fenegbin(Conflict ~ l(Project_n,0:2)+
                        Urban_area+
                        Econ_dev, TC_test,panel.id = ~ID+Year)


structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 19, 19, 
19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
25, 25, 25, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 
28, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 31, 
31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 31, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 
33, 33, 33, 33, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 
36, 36, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 38, 
39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 42, 42, 
42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 44, 44, 44, 44, 
44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 
46, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 47, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 50, 
50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 66, 66, 66, 
66, 66, 66, 66, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 67, 72, 72, 72, 72, 72, 
72, 72, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 75, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 76, 
77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 77, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 78, 79, 79, 
79, 79, 79, 79, 79, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 80, 81, 81, 81, 81, 
81, 81, 81, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 83, 
83, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 84, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 85, 87, 
87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 87, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 93, 98, 98, 98, 
98, 98, 98, 98), Year = c(2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 
2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 
2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 
2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 
2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 
2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 
2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 
2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 
2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 
2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 
2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010
), Conflict = c(4, 8, 8, 1, 8, 0, 0, 10, 10, 4, 1, 5, 0, 0, 34, 
25, 13, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
), Project_n = c(9, 19, 26, 40, 66, 92, 122, 10, 19, 30, 47, 
82, 124, 153, 13, 19, 27, 42, 67, 102, 132, 14, 20, 29, 39, 62, 
95, 126, 8, 13, 20, 34, 58, 88, 116, 15, 21, 30, 43, 69, 99, 
124, 13, 19, 34, 73, 110, 149, 183, 8, 13, 20, 33, 58, 88, 118, 
9, 17, 26, 42, 69, 106, 136, 10, 15, 24, 37, 62, 95, 125, 9, 
17, 23, 34, 58, 91, 125, 8, 13, 20, 33, 58, 87, 118, 13, 19, 
26, 40, 66, 101, 132, 12, 17, 24, 34, 56, 86, 111, 11, 16, 23, 
40, 65, 102, 129, 7, 12, 19, 34, 58, 86, 118, 12, 19, 28, 42, 
65, 92, 122, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 3, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3), Urban_area = c(6L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 19L, 22L, 
24L, 430L, 467L, 486L, 508L, 532L, 551L, 567L, 27L, 32L, 43L, 
44L, 47L, 47L, 50L, 19L, 22L, 27L, 32L, 35L, 37L, 40L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 12L, 16L, 18L, 26L, 28L, 32L, 37L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 12L, 18L, 
25L, 35L, 50L, 61L, 70L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 17L, 17L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 
14L, 14L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 20L, 2L, 
4L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 71L, 
73L, 75L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 76L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 44L, 
10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 35L, 37L, 37L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 38L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 34L, 
34L, 34L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 35L, 35L, 37L, 37L, 40L, 
42L, 47L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 
31L, 36L, 117L, 119L, 120L, 124L, 128L, 131L, 133L, 146L, 164L, 
172L, 180L, 188L, 194L, 199L, 16L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 22L, 25L, 
24L, 27L, 28L, 31L, 32L, 34L, 34L, 92L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 
107L, 107L, 868L, 1158L, 1173L, 1201L, 1217L, 1237L, 1254L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 16L, 31L, 35L, 36L, 39L, 42L, 47L, 48L, 
43L, 50L, 58L, 65L, 73L, 86L, 94L, 70L, 91L, 95L, 97L, 101L, 
103L, 105L, 77L, 78L, 81L, 83L, 85L, 87L, 92L, 41L, 44L, 44L, 
44L, 44L, 44L, 46L, 60L, 67L, 71L, 77L, 80L, 82L, 83L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 87L, 87L, 89L, 93L, 94L, 97L, 99L, 79L, 
80L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 81L, 82L, 32L, 37L, 37L, 39L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 25L, 29L, 42L, 49L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 14L, 
20L, 92L, 96L, 96L, 102L, 116L, 121L, 130L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
16L, 19L, 21L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 27L, 27L, 25L, 34L, 39L, 
42L, 51L, 65L, 79L, 156L, 157L, 157L, 158L, 164L, 168L, 173L, 
89L, 90L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 91L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
30L, 30L, 33L, 36L, 37L, 40L, 42L, 439L, 444L, 446L, 449L, 450L, 
450L, 453L, 78L, 85L, 93L, 111L, 125L, 143L, 152L, 876L, 894L, 
902L, 915L, 928L, 935L, 949L, 2348L, 2578L, 2781L, 2894L, 2999L, 
3100L, 3197L), Econ_dev = c(4804, 4018, 4559, 4324, 4047, 3975, 
4598, 2919, 2663, 3593, 4003, 3563, 3742, 4250, 6794, 5408, 6320, 
6480, 6266, 6028, 7014, 12128, 9850, 11035, 11463, 11430, 11011, 
12261, 10278, 7891, 8543, 8422, 9757, 8692, 8553, 6769, 5920, 
6429, 6211, 5815, 5881, 6250, 8169, 6954, 7142, 7383, 7119, 7084, 
7828, 5615, 4360, 5247, 5413, 5162, 5323, 5853, 4764, 3881, 4213, 
4307, 4258, 4203, 4690, 7394, 5704, 6391, 6618, 7041, 6397, 7342, 
11966, 10659, 9749, 9852, 9541, 9825, 9951, 2562, 2116, 2386, 
2393, 2370, 2306, 2720, 9475, 7036, 7627, 7185, 7908, 7243, 7849, 
3120, 2543, 2914, 2934, 2935, 2878, 3292, 5696, 4376, 5401, 5347, 
5182, 5107, 5859, 10031, 8541, 7087, 8038, 7307, 8327, 7997, 
13052, 12392, 9091, 9578, 9947, 10638, 11015, 457, 340, 363, 
406, 383, 394, 449, 154550, 120170, 138342, 151295, 144230, 138545, 
153883, 180, 129, 142, 169, 147, 155, 174, 94428, 69831, 80755, 
88288, 84440, 81075, 91466, 58166, 42476, 55340, 61178, 57181, 
57125, 64128, 498, 366, 489, 536, 486, 503, 574, 41844, 29495, 
40868, 42019, 41238, 39604, 43691, 83539, 59038, 80555, 85249, 
81528, 82336, 90101, 59722, 43517, 57493, 60387, 58817, 59445, 
64507, 59951, 42007, 58137, 60935, 58607, 58582, 65854, 31267, 
22966, 30560, 31088, 30735, 30003, 33126, 2536, 1855, 2406, 2536, 
2530, 2539, 2852, 97187, 72994, 90563, 98522, 95002, 99091, 97679, 
105600, 88835, 111129, 110397, 106636, 110715, 109066, 40362, 
31781, 39175, 41981, 39824, 41354, 42460, 444, 316, 397, 531, 
477, 462, 569, 9443, 8655, 9772, 10971, 11727, 12359, 15013, 
122314, 98940, 125682, 118406, 116651, 126242, 121709, 107492, 
92109, 113548, 112005, 107757, 116638, 109503, 88132, 67325, 
81771, 93299, 86295, 86996, 89413, 97902, 86883, 95488, 97593, 
97985, 104361, 100891, 133807, 103742, 109176, 112468, 109876, 
130087, 106315, 195783, 175887, 195243, 185581, 183746, 191335, 
188783, 96324, 76212, 77521, 83088, 83716, 93338, 78491, 73514, 
67258, 81518, 77334, 80119, 87578, 80922, 622, 482, 617, 747, 
690, 630, 825, 41875, 27657, 35017, 38052, 37200, 33456, 38477, 
126170, 86623, 117948, 127197, 124610, 117928, 129537, 65893, 
47938, 58724, 59922, 59452, 61282, 64461, 731, 618, 825, 738, 
819, 711, 797, 119483, 77538, 100933, 97671, 100074, 98796, 104611, 
29466, 21157, 28695, 28822, 28364, 29201, 29435, 70, 46, 65, 
61, 60, 60, 60, 70926, 52382, 66268, 69232, 68998, 66811, 70557, 
440, 354, 418, 417, 397, 432, 520, 33580, 24738, 31848, 32536, 
32581, 32132, 33515, 30853, 24034, 29418, 27064, 26928, 28679, 
26238, 42286, 32087, 38332, 40977, 40642, 41642, 41672, 3259, 
2469, 3016, 3014, 3210, 3098, 3198, 93270, 63597, 80240, 77919, 
72782, 77182, 73481, 1583, 1674, 1773, 1233, 1062, 1265, 1247, 
71635, 61740, 69084, 69177, 67109, 71640, 74626)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-413L))
>
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: If you could provide enough data and code to make your example reproducible on our machines, I'm sure we could help.

Comment: @AllanCameron I hope my edits are sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is to predict the outcome if you hold all other variables steady at their average values over a three year period. Then, predict the number of conflicts in the third year if there were 0 projects in year 1, but an average number of projects in years two and three. Do the same for an average number of projects in the first and third years, but 0 in the second year. Finally, predict conflicts if there are an average number of projects in the first two years, but 0 in year 3. This will show you the effect of having 0  projects at lags 2, 1 and 0.

Now do the same set of calculations for each number of projects you want to plot (say all values from 0 to 50 projects). You could do this as follows:

```r
mean_proj <- mean(TC_test$Project_n)

plot_df <- cbind(n_proj = 0:50, do.call(rbind, lapply(0:50, function(x) {
  data.frame(`two years ago` = predict(model_test, 
        newdata = data.frame(Urban_area = mean(TC_test$Urban_area), 
                             Project_n = c(x, mean_proj, mean_proj), 
                             Econ_dev = mean(TC_test$Urban_area), 
                             Year = 2010:2012, ID = 1), type = 'response')[3],
    `last year` = predict(model_test, 
        newdata = data.frame(Urban_area = mean(TC_test$Urban_area), 
                             Project_n = c(mean_proj, x, mean_proj), 
                             Econ_dev = mean(TC_test$Urban_area), 
                             Year = 2010:2012, ID = 1), type = 'response')[3],
    `current year` = predict(model_test, 
        newdata = data.frame(Urban_area = mean(TC_test$Urban_area), 
                             Project_n = c(mean_proj, mean_proj, x), 
                             Econ_dev = mean(TC_test$Urban_area), 
                             Year = 2010:2012, ID = 1), type = 'response')[3],
    check.names = FALSE)
})))
```

Now you can plot the result in three facets, one to show the marginal effect of the number of projects at each lag:

```r
library(tidyverse)

plot_df %>%
  pivot_longer(-n_proj) %>%
  ggplot(aes(n_proj, value, color = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous('Number of conflicts') +
  scale_x_continuous('Number of projects') +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1', guide = 'none') +
  facet_wrap(.~name, scales = 'free_y') +
  ggtitle('Predicted conflicts given number of projects...') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(fill = NA, color = 'gray80'))
```

[image]